# An attempt was made to set a report parameter 'Name' that is not defined in this report?

Tags: asp.net, parameters

I am trying to load a report that filters by the name in textbox1 but I am getting the error "An attempt was made to set a report parameter 'Name' that is not defined in this report" Any ideas?

```
Dim ds As New TestDataSetTableAdapters.tblTestDataTableAdapter 

        ' Create report data source 
        Dim ID As ReportParameter 
        ID = New ReportParameter("Name", TextBox1.Text) 

        Dim rds As New ReportDataSource("MyApplication_ModelObject", ObjectDataSource1) 

        ' Clear the datasets in the report viewer and add the new datasource 
        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear() 
        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds) 
        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(ID) 
        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Name` part of the *ReportParameter* must match the name of the parameter in the Report.

It's probably `@Name`, best this to do is to open the report and check there.

Comment: Thanks that fixed that error but now when my report loads there is nothing but a message that says A data source instance has not been supplied for the data source 'DataSet1'.

Comment: open a new question for that one, could be a lot of things, credentials are quite likley though.

Comment: You should also check for spelling and capitalization: report parameters are case sensitive.